# Unespected Error in LinkAssemblies Task (Xamarin C#)

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a cellphone app and i'm getting this error:

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
Error       Error inesperado en la tarea "LinkAssemblies".
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: 
Could not resolve reference to 'System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement' 
(defined in assembly 'protobuf-net, Version=1.0.0.282, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67') with scope 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. When the scope is different from the defining 
assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: 
Failed to resolve System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   en Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   en Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() SincronTestAndroid.Android  



ask for any code you need, don't know exactly what show to you right now.
```

I Saw this question asked before but noone has find an all use answer for any of them, So i post this now to see if somebody can, at least help me fixing this iteration of the error.

Any constructive question, comment or request for clarification would be valued to

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you set your `Linker` setting to `Don't Link` does your project work? If so, then a type in `System.ServiceModel` is being linked away and you will need to apply a linkskip to it. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#linkskip

Comment: Sure, i can try, Where i can set that?